# How do I modify strcat so that it wouldn't edit str1

Tags: c++, c, windows

Why does strcat gives me its version of str1? As far as I know there has to be & thing before paramatater in function prototype and implementation if you want to get it editted, but I don't see it here.

```
char *strcat( char *str1, const char *str2 );
```

How do I edit this function so that it would only return new string but leave out the ones I give it?
My try

```
char *strApp(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    size_t i,j;
    size_t k = 0;
    for (i = 0; dest[i] != '\0'; i++);
    char rdest[100];
    do {
        rdest[k] = dest[k];
    } while(++k<=i);
    for (j = 0; src[j] != '\0'; j++)
        rdest[i+j] = src[j];

    rdest[i+j] = '\0';
    return rdest;
}
```

It damages second string. Could anyone give me safe and correct version? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you dealing with `char*` pointers in c++?

Comment: the pointer is not changed, so referene for parameter.

Comment: rdest will get out of scope and the returned pointer will be invalid.

Comment: The C++ tag seems misplaced.

Comment: What should I be dealing with?

Comment: Given the `windows` tag, the compiler vendor has probably misrepresented to OP that `c` and `c++` are basically the same language...

Comment: I made rdest global variable, and it works, thanks P. Stelian. But is my code as efficient as possible?

Comment: Making `rdest` global is a problematic fix.  The next time you call `strApp()` with two new strings, your previous result will be clobbered.  You really need to dynamically allocate (and later free) memory for the new string.  Instead of doing this in a rewrite of `strcat()`, you could do it before calling C's own `strcat()`.  See my (revised) example below.

Comment: I won't need previous result by the time next strApp() will be called. So, can I expect everything to be smooth with this?

Comment: You should generally allocate `char rdest[]` with the appropriate size (length of the two strings + 1) **outside** function `strApp`, and pass it as an argument to this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *strApp(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char *pointer = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1);

    if (pointer == NULL)
    {
        perror("failed to allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 

    return strcat(strcpy(pointer, s1), s2);
}

int main()
{

    char *s1 = "original";

    char *s2 = " modified";

    char *s3 = strApp(s1, s2);

    printf("%s\n", s1);

    printf("%s\n", s2);

    printf("%s\n", s3);

    free(s3);

    return 0;
}
```

Just trying to point out you don't need to completely rewrite `strcat()` to get what you want.

Comment: Undefined behaviour: you're appending to a buffer that cannot hold any more characters. Not a good example at all.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, yes that was a blunder!  The type that C happily allows us make.  I've replaced the `strdup()` with a proper `malloc()`

Comment: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: with strdup: error: invalid conversion from 'size_t {aka unsigned int}' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: "void * is automatically and safely promoted to any other pointer type" per [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).  As far as `strdup()`, that was already dealt with two comments prior.

Comment: What to do if it does fail to allocate memory?

Comment: As written, it exits to the operating system.  You originally allocated 100 characters to `rdest` -- if your program can't come up with 100 characters of dynamic memory, you've got bigger problems than `strApp()` so continuing to execute seems a questionable choice.

Comment: This needlessly finds the length of the each string twice. The solution I posted addresses this problem.

Comment: @cdlane, I'm using Linux, and I just saw the source for `strdup` on Linux, and it doesn't set `errno` explicitly after a failed `malloc`, so I retract my comment. [This comment will self-destruct]

Answer (score 0):

strcat is, by definition, altering the target. If you don't want to, you should make a copy yourself in a target memory location you allocate yourself.

Comment: strcpy performs the copy. You still need to allocate a target for the copy large enough to hold both strings and the final NUL terminator.

Answer (score 0):

*You've tagged your question with both C and C++. I'm providing a C solution. Adjustments may be needed for C++.*

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>   
#include <string.h>

char* strdupcat(const char* s1, const char* s2) {
    size_t s1_len = strlen(s1);
    size_t s2_len = strlen(s2);
    char* s = malloc(s1_len + s2_len + 1);

    if (s == NULL)
        return NULL;

    {
        char* s_end = s;
        s_end = mempcpy(s_end, s1, s1_len);
        s_end = mempcpy(s_end, s2, s2_len);
        *s_end = '\0';
    }

    return s;
}
```

Example usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char* s = strdupcat("abc", "def");
    if (s == NULL) {
        perror("Can't concatenate");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    puts(s);
    free(s);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This function is used similarly to `strdup`.

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The **`strdupcat()`** function returns a pointer to a new string which is a  duplicate of the string `s1` with a duplicate of string `s2` appended. Memory for the new string is obtained with **`malloc`(3)**, and can be freed with **`free`(3)**.
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> The **`strdupcat()`** function returns a pointer to the duplicated string, or `NULL` if insufficient memory was available.
>
> **ERRORS**
>
> **`ENOMEM`** Insufficient memory available to allocate the new string.

You can use `strerror` or `perror` to obtain an error message when `strdupcat()` returns `NULL`.

---

Here's a version that accepts an arbitrary number of arguments:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* strdupcatmany(int dummy, ...) {
#define strdupcatmany(...) strdupcatmany(0, __VA_ARGS__, NULL)
    size_t len = 0;
    char* s;
    char* s_dst;
    const char* s_src;
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, dummy);
    while (1) {
        s_src = va_arg(ap, const char*);
        if (s_src == NULL)
            break;

        len += strlen(s_src);
    }
    va_end(ap);

    s = malloc(len + 1);
    if (s == NULL)
        return NULL;

    s_dst = s;
    va_start(ap, dummy);
    while (1) {
        s_src = va_arg(ap, const char*);
        if (s_src == NULL)
            break;

        s_dst = stpcpy(s_dst, s_src);
    }
    va_end(ap);
    *s_dst = '\0';

    return s;
}
```

For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char* s = strdupcatmany("abc", "def", "ghi");
    if (s == NULL) {
        perror("Can't concatenate");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    puts(s);
    free(s);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note: I don't know how portable `__VA_ARGS__` args is.

Comment: And in the place I call strcpycat I also add `free(s);` after it?

Comment: Yes, it returns memory allocated by `malloc`, so it needs to be deallocated using `free`. I've added some documentation to my answer.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity I used cdlane's version.If I use it like this, will there be a problem? `s4 = strApp(strApp(s1, s2)),s3)`?

Comment: One bracket too many, but you get the point. I wonder if second time it will allocate new memory for new variables or not or will it consider the same variables and won't allocate memory because it already got some?

Comment: Yeah, memory leak. You have no way of getting the memory allocated by the first call. It's also multiplying the wastefulness

Comment: So I can't use it like that? Because as far as I tried it looks ok

Comment: Again,  it suffers from a memory leak. You need to store the value returned by the inner call so you can call `free` on it

Comment: Wait just a minute, first @Brackets says, "I won't need previous result by the time next strApp() will be called" while defending his global variable solution and  second, `strdupcat(strdupcat(s1, s2), s3)` has the same memory leak which your comment fails to mention!  You can pile up the calls something like: char *s4, *s5; s5 = strApp(s4 = strApp(s1, s2), s3); ...; free(s4); free(s5);

Comment: @cdlane, Of course `strdupcat(strdupcat(s1, s2), s3)` has the same problem. He didn't ask about that.

Comment: @Brackets, I've added `strdupcatmany` to my answer so you can do `strdupcatmany(s1, s2, s3)` or even `strdupcatmany(s1, s2, s3, s4)`. (I also simplified my original solution my replacing `memcpy` with `mempcpy`.)